# Can't open window manager after fiddling with compton(also the header of my applications are gone)

Tags: xfce, window-manager, graphics, xubuntu, compton

[image]

That's what it looks like.

I was trying to get frosted windows with compton but after making a mistake in my config froze the system and got a black screen on boot. So I went into recovery and purged compton but now there are still those problems.

I'm using xubuntu lts btw

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could run, from a terminal:

```
xfwm4 --replace
```

It is the XFCE window manager.

Comment: Xfwm4 libm.so.6 version glibc_2.29 not. Found